# PHP : Multiple cURL with same URL

Tags: php, forms, curl

I have a form on my website calling a webservice via cURL with post datas on submit.

This is working great except in one case, when the distant webservice servers are down (it happens frequently)
So I'm trying to develop a cache system which will work as follow :

- If the curl execution on form submit returns false I save it in database
- I'm running a CRON job every day to check if I have some failed submissions
- I'm doing a foreach on my results set and running a curl call for each submissions

The problem is how to proceed for the last step ? The URL is always the same ( just the POST field changes on each call) and I want to check if each call is valid (let's imagine the distant server go down after the 10 first submissions, I want to save in my database that the first 10 are OK but not the others left)

I tried with this function I found :

```
function curl_multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;

    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}
```

my array looks like :

```
    array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["post"]=>
    string(1644) "Surname=Test&Name=Test"
    ["url"]=>
    string(28) "http://www.mywebsite.fr/"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["post"]=>
    string(1644) "Surname=Test1&Name=Test1"
    ["url"]=>
    string(28) "http://www.mywebsite.fr/"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
     ["post"]=>
    string(1644) "Surname=Test2&Name=Test2"
    ["url"]=>
    string(28) "http://www.mywebsite.fr/"
  }

}
```

but when the URL is not valid (I tried with a non-valid URL to simulate a down server) I have this :

```
    Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/www/myscript.php on line 63

Warning: (null)(): 560 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
```

Am I doing it wrong ?

Thank you

Edit 1 : I tried to implement bishop answer like this :

```
$myarray=array(
    array(
        "id"=>"1",
        "post"=>"Surname=Test&Name=Test",
        "url"=>"http://www.mywebsite.fr/",
    )
  ,  array(
        "id"=>"1",
        "post"=>"Surname=Test&Name=Test",
        "url"=>"http://www.mywebsite.fr/",
    )
);

    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach($myarray as $k=>$failed){

            $myarray[$k]["handle"] = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($myarray[$k]["handle"], CURLOPT_URL, $failed["url"]);
        curl_setopt($myarray[$k]["handle"], CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($myarray[$k]["handle"], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $failed["post"]);
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $myarray[$k]["handle"]);
        }


 foreach (multiread($mh) as $info) {
    var_dump($info);
}
```

But the request seems never to stop if the distant URL is unreachable. Is there a way to limit time spent to execute on each request ?

Edit 2 : 
Is is a good way to use this when defining the options ?

```
curl_setopt($chs[$key], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 10);
```

and at the top of the script

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

If this is OK my last problem is to gather informations about each call. How can I separately retrieve informations about each handler (to save in database that this call was a success ?) Like an ID or so ?

Comment: The example as given works for me (ie, it returns reasonably quickly with a response). Is there a particular URL that is giving you trouble?

Comment: No i'm just trying with non-existing URL to simulate a down distant server.
I tried from another server it seems to work better but the echo is just : 
NULL

Comment: By default, curl *outputs* the result. You want to *return* the result. In your initialization loop, add this: `curl_setopt($myarray[$k]["handle"], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

Comment: OK that's good to know. But I'm calling three URLs and I was expecting to have a response about each transfer to know if everything was sent without problem (and save to database that this call was a success). There I'm just having "0" one time, on three calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop over the multi-handles doesn't appear complete. A more robust implementation:

```
function multiread($mh, $timeout = .5) {
    $output = array ();
    $runCnt = 0;
    do {
        // start requests, or update status of pending requests: returns by
        // reference (in $runCnt) the number of outstanding requests
        $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runCnt);
        if (CURLM_OK !== $status) throw new \RuntimeException;

        // take a breath, so as to not eat 100% CPU
        do {
            $status = curl_multi_select($mh, $timeout);
            if (-1 === $status) {
                usleep(10);
            }
        } while (0 === $status);

        // gather the results and yield back what we know
        while (false !== ($info = curl_multi_info_read($mh))) {
            if (CURLE_OK === $info['result']) {
                $output[] = [ $info, curl_multi_getcontent($info['handle']) ];
            } else {
                $output[] = [ $info, null ];
            }
        }
    } while (0 < $runCnt);
    return $output;
}
```

Now do some looping:

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
// ... add your easy handles

foreach (multiread($mh) as list ($info, $content)) {
    // $info['handle'] contains the cURL easy handle
    // $info['result'] contains the result code, see also curl_strerror
    // $content contains whatever the URL returned
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! But as my PHP version is 5.2 and I have no option to change it , do you think I can achieve this in another way ? :(

Comment: Is there any way to replace yield by something else ?

Comment: @pepichoc Edited to a version that supports PHP < 5.5.

Comment: OK it's working (with some minor changes on declaring array in your function for PHP <5.5) but it seems never to stop. If the server is down for 3 hours I don't want it to try for 3 hours. I edited my question above.